# If the Ark was found today how should it be handled Halachicly?

Tags: halacha, ark-aron-kodesh, archaeology

Imagine that the Aron Kodesh that contains the two sets of tablets given at Sinai, which was hidden away towards the end of the first temple period, was found today (in modern times).

What are the Halachic implications of handling it, like purity/impurity, Kohanim Meyuchasim, places it can be moved to etc?

What would be the proper procedure for removing it from where it was found, and where should it be stored?

Comment: What's wrong with leaving it where it is?

Comment: @DoubleAA presumably its in the ground which is a bizayon

Comment: You think Yoshiyahu placed it in a bizayon place for a few thousand years of storage??? Presumably not!

Comment: @DoubleAA Please reopen it as the other question does not deal with Halachic aspects of handling the Ark, like טומאה בציבור etc.

Comment: I don’t think this is a duplicate. This one asks about the halachic issues, while that one asks about the hashkafic ones.

Comment: @rikitikitembo Isn’t that what you do with all your Sheimos? Ultimately it’s buried.

Comment: @donielf well at least the current version does

Comment: @DoubleAA I’m not so sure that the initial revision wasn’t also, but yes, certainly the current revision.